# How to import data and automatically create time series from csv files to Apache IoTDB?

Tags: import, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is there a tool for importing time series into Apache IoTDB? I checked and know that IoTDB has "import-csv" function, but looks like it can only import data into IoTDB. What I expect is that I can write all data in csv, and can directly import data AND automatically form time series in IoTDB. Are there any ways to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, Apache IoTDB cannot create time series directly from csv files. You can write a program to read csv, and use `jdbc` or `session` interface to establish it in IoTDB.
By the way, IoTDB does not need to create a schema in advance, because it can be automatically created when writing data. This means that if you using API interfaces such as `session` to write data into IoTDB, we can specify the schema when writing data and you don't need to create it by hand in advance.